# Headlights have to be switched off twice when vehicle isn't running for headlights to actually turn off

Tags: electrical, headlight, chrysler

I have a 2006 Jeep Liberty with manual light switches. I noticed shortly after buying it several years ago that if I turn the car off before switching the headlights off, and then switch them off they don't go off. However, if I switch them back on again and off again, they then turn off.

I thought this was just some electrical issue that I could live with until I recently bought a 2001 Dodge Dakota that does the exact same thing. Obviously both vehicles are Chryslers, so now I am thinking there are two possibilities. This is some odd and unhelpful "feature", or the electrical component that Chrysler used to switch the headlights on and off is prone to fail in this rather interesting way.

Has anyone seen/heard of this before? Is it something I can fix?

Comment: Some cars are designed so the headlights stay on for a minute or two before shutting off automatically, this is to give you some light when getting out. Does the light turn off by itself?

Comment: I suspect this vehicle has been optioned with "Follow Me Home" headlights.  The idea is they stay on for long enough for you to exit the vehicle and make it to your front door.  As previous comment, try locking the vehicle and seeing if they switch themselves off after a number of minutes.

Comment: @GdD I have never waited to see if they turn themselves off, I will have to try that, how long is too long to wait?

Comment: I don't know @J-Rome, it depends on the car, but anything more than 5 minutes would seem like too much. I'd expect 1-2 minutes is most likely. Try locking your car and seeing how long they stay on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A feature of many newer cars is for the headlights to stay on for a time after you get out of the car so you have some light to unpack, then the headlights go off after a time. The timer may be from when you lock the doors, or when you get out depending on the model. Try locking the car and leaving it for a few minutes, the lights should go off by themselves.